# SQL Select records where any word / value contained within one string is also contained within another string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I need to find a SQL **select** query that will allow me to find records in [KnowledgeArticle] Where any word contained in the string [KnowledgeArticle].[Keywords] is contained within [Incident].[Description].

I'm working with an IT Service Management application, and want to provide a list of Knowledge articles that match an Incident record's description, automatically. I don't have direct access to change the way this ITSM application queries the database, it's all managed via a series of GUI's.

However, I can connect the ITSM app to views that I create in the database, and filter results of the view from there.

So, my challenge is that I need to get, within a view, a list of all [KnowledgeArticle] records, duplicated once for each [Incident] record, where any word within [Incident].[Description] is contained within [KnowledgeArticle].[Keywords].

This query on it's own would be quite ridiculous, and would present a very large subset of records, however once I have the query built and set up as a view, I'll be able to configure the ITSM application to filter the results of this query / view to only the current [Incident] record, providing me with the data that I need (Knowledge articles where any keyword in the knowledge article is present on the Incident).

Hopefully this makes sense, I'm not sure what kind of operator I might be able to use in a comparison clause to bring up that list of knowledge article records.

(If you're not familiar with IT Service Management jargon, the words Incident and KnowledgeArticle are just table names, what they do is less important to the technical question being asked).

Comment: What RDBMS (SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) are you using?  And what version (SQL Server 2016, etc.)

Comment: @ScottHodgin MS SQL Server 2014, but if there's a way to do it on MS SQL Server 2016 that is fine, too

Comment: Keywords is a single string?

Comment: @Paparazzi Keywords is a single string; it's a field in our application that someone enters keywords into. This is later used elsewhere in the application (unrelated to what I'm doing here) using full-text search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work, although I must warn it seems VERY inefficient especially given the projected size of a Knowledge Base type database.  I agree with the other answer that this may not be best handled by anything that's not a Data Quality/Analysis tool.

If Oracle or any RDBMS that uses pipes to concat:

```
SELECT 
t1.col1,
t2.col1
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.col1 LIKE '%' || t2.col2 || '%'
```

If SQL Server or any RDBMS that uses + to concat:

```
SELECT 
t1.col1,
t2.col1
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.col1 LIKE '%' + t2.col2 + '%'
```

I just tried it on a few sample tables and it seemed to work, and you can substitute INNER with LEFT if you don't need them to match.

Edit: just realized you're asking for ANY word in one column being contained in any other column.  That's rough.  Cursor may do the trick there.

Update: As per comment about using STRING_SPLIT with SQL Server, the following will find words from t1.col1 that appear in t2.col1

```
SELECT 
    t1.col1,
    t2.col1
FROM (
    SELECT t1.col1, v.value AS word
    FROM table1 t1
    CROSS APPLY  STRING_SPLIT(t.col1, ' ') AS v
) AS t1
INNER JOIN  table2 t2
    ON '%' + t1.word+ '%' LIKE t2.col2
```

Comment: "*or any RDBMS that uses pipes*" should be "or any RDBMS that sticks to the SQL standard"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Amen!

Comment: For SQL Server you could solve the "any word in one column" with the SPLIT function.  Something like...

    SELECT 
     t1.col1,
     t2.col1
    FROM (
     SELECT t1.col1, v.value AS word
     FROM table1 t1
     CROSS APPLY  STRING_SPLIT(t.col1, ' ') AS v
    ) AS t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2
        ON '%' + t1.word+ '%' LIKE t2.col2

Comment: Well, in our case we're talking about a small implementation that will have at most ~50-60 users... I wanted to try it out and see. In the case of this answer, would it then require that the entire value of t2.col2 be within t1.col1? The issue i'm facing is it could be just part of t2.col2, not the whole thing, that I'd be trying to match... I think I need to pursue Kent's idea

Comment: @KentChenery I'll try this, it seems like it might be what I'm looking for :)

Comment: Note - On my personal machine that I was testing on, I'm using a newer sql version (2016 I think). Our actual dev environment is on 2014. STRING_SPLIT() function requires compatibility level of 130 or greater, which requires SQL 2016+

Comment: @schizoid04 this is why I didn't suggest that function.  it's a great function, no doubt about that, but the adoption rate of 2016 isn't extremely high yet so not everyone has it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the requirements of your project but with the info you provided on this post, this qualify for a data quality project from Data Quality Services (DQS):

[Data Quality Project (DQS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/data-quality-services/data-quality-projects-dqs)

Comment: This seems somewhat different than what I'm asking.... I'm not familiar with DQS, but it doesn't seem like something I could turn into a view for the application that I need it for. I'm not trying to reduce duplication of data, as the data matching section there says it's for. I'm trying to find relevant records in one table by checking whether it contains a value from another.

Comment: I'm with Eduardo on this.  While the main feature of Data Quality software is to de-dupe/aggregate/combine, you may also find that it's useful to analyze and more aggressively index your data so it's "searchable" without causing such a strain on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Based off of @KentChenery's comment, I was able to get to this point, which shows me a list of words contained in the Description field on the Incident table that are also contained within the Keywords field (which holds many different words) on the KnowledgeArticle table.

I have to refine this a bit from this point, but the hard part is over. Will update when it's done.

```
SELECT t1.word, t2.Keywords 

FROM ( SELECT t1.Description, v.value AS word FROM Incident t1 
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(
Convert(varchar(max),t1.Description), ' '
) AS v ) AS t1 

INNER JOIN  KnowledgeArticle t2 ON t2.Keywords Like ('%' + t1.word+ '%')
```

Comment: Dont expect it to perform well!  This problem as a whole is better served with some kind of full text engine or a back ground process doing post processing to do this work.

Comment: I understand. It seems to perform well enough for me so far, there will be some constraints added to this such that it will only be searching for a select (pun) group of records.